# Referencing large documents

Tags: discussion, references, specific-question

Is it acceptable practice to cite a large document as a reference, without explaining which part of the document supports the claim being made or quoting the relevant section?

For example, [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/31538/104) cites videos, a 16 page PDF and an entire book in the first two paragraphs, with no time information or page numbers or quotation.